# Cape not falling down in simulation

Tags: animation, objects, cloth-simulation

ive been busy trying to figure out Blender the past few days.
I havent had any experience with modeling or even photoshopping in overal, so this is totally new for me.

I just got done with the head and body modelling and wanted to put a cape on, i followed a tutorial did the exact same things, now the cape is made  and i tried simulating it.
On the toturial the body doesnt move, the only thing that moves is the cape.

On my simulation as you can see on the link below, my Body moves,  the eyes and cape do not move.
I think you get the problem.

Hope you can help me out

[image: Screenshot]

Edit:     Alright i think i saw what the problem of the body was :  The cloth Modifier for the body was on.       i put it off and it doesnt fall down now.

Now only the cape...

Edit 2:
I made the cape look collide too,  now the problem is that it doesnt collide well with the body.

everything goes fine except it going THROUGH the hands, not colliding with it, is this because there arent many 'steps' like i had to do with the hair to calculate the colliding? if yes how do i change it?.

Comment: add more loop cuts or use the subsurf modifier before the cloth modifier

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do believe that you are correct in thinking that you need to up the steps of the simulation. You can find those in the cloth modifier tab under "Physics" in the Properties.[image: The steps can be set up to 80]

Also, check if the hands and other body parts that need to collide have the collision in the "Physics" tab. More important, however, is proper subdivision. Make sure that the hand has proper subdivision and the cape is not only subdivided in one or two axis. For example make sure it looks like this: [image: Subdivided 10 times in all axis]

And not this:[image: Subdivided 10 times in only two axis]